# c++ use & to create pointer member from objects in array [error]

Tags: c++, arrays, function, object

Hello I am sorry this shouldn't be a hard problem. Im trying to get the pointer to call that objects function in the array. the block id is the key, however i cannot seem to get it running.

```
blocks* objects[28];
int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 0; j < 6; j++)
        {
            objects[index] = new blocks(key, i, j);
            key = key + 1;  //used to make sure each block can id with a key
            index = index + 1;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 28; i++)
    {
        double id = objects[i]->getblockid(); //FIXED
        cout << "Object is: " << i << " id is: " << id << endl;
    }
```

Comment: what is the error? btw `objects[i]->getblockid;` doesnt seem right, unless its a public member.

Comment: It seems to me that you're only initializing the first six elements of the array.

Comment: yes thats the error saying i need a pointer "&"

Comment: provide the exact error message within your question please

Comment: add the declaration of `blocks`.

Comment: no please dont add the declaration of blocks. there are already enough errors to solve without it ;)

Comment: Each time through the `j` loop you're overwriting `objects[i]`, resulting in object leaks for the blocks that were allocated the previous times.

Comment: its something with that line. blocks is a simple public member with functions. its has to due with the fact that the array has objects in them. so how would i call a function such as "." would do

Comment: @tobi303 Don't we need to see that to know why it's reporting an error when dereferencing `blocks*`?

Comment: @user3550526 Is `getblockid` a data or function member? The name sounds like a function.

Comment: @barmar isnt it obvious? I would bet that blocks has a method `getblockid()` and he is trying to call it without the bracktes

Comment: when i use the dot aka '.' is saids expression must have class type?

Comment: each time your doing 6 new calls for the same memory location in the inner for loop  'objects[i] = new blocks(key, i, j);' causing a leak, then you only end up with 6 allocated objects at the end of the double for loops but iterating over all 28

Comment: yes that got rid of the error i was forgetting the (). now to fix this overwriting

Comment: @user3550526 Next time post a [MCVE] including all of the exact error messages you get please. This will save you and others a lot of time.

Comment: i will not post whole bunch a code. im only going to post the selection with the problem for ease to everyone else. no need to make it messy looking...

Comment: @user3550526 _"i will not post whole bunch a code."_ Did I ask for that? You seem to miss the _minimal_ from the link. Also you missed the point to post exact, verbatim error messages you got.

Comment: noone asked you to put a "whole bunch", a MCVE is what you get after removing anything irrelevant from the code, while still reproducing the same error

Comment: @user3550526 With your last edit you made your question completely useless now. That's not how things work here, rolling back. Please do what advised instead,. You might even post your own answer describing the fix.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that your code doesn't compile? It seems fine for me.

Howerver I can see see a few problems at runtime.

First, in inner loop you are instantiating block object 21 times, but you operate on only first 6 elements of this array. So when you are iterating from 0 to 28 in last loop, you will get exception thrown since 7th and further elements are not instantiated. This is because 7th element of this array is not instantiated. It points to some memory location which is just a garbage.

The other problem is that when you overwrite your pointers, you loose information of created objects, this causes memory leaks. Perhaps you should familiarize yourself with smart pointers concept?

Use `std::vectors` instead of vanila arrays. Alternatively use `std::array`.

You should also familiarize with concept of iterators.

Comment: _"It seems fine for me."_ How can you know that from an incomplete sample? Also while your suggestions are good, that's not really an answer for a _non question_.

Comment: I guessed you need block class, which must have public variable of type double. So I added it. Block's ctor you can infere from code as well.

Yes, it is a bit game of guessing.

Comment: Don't guess on unclear questions please. Gain enough rep to comment to ask for clarifications (getting 50 isn't that hard).